# How can I export a Sitecore website into XML files?

Tags: xml, export, sitecore

I need to export XML files from our Sitecore site for localization purposes. I know it is not the best solution but it is the only way we have. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

1. Log into the Sitecore Desktop.
2. From the Sitecore menu, select
   "Control Panel."
3. Go into the "Globalization" category.
4. Choose the "Export languages to a file" task and follow the instructions.

Detailed instructions with screenshots can be found [here](http://blog.globalizationpartners.com/sitecore-content-localization.aspx).

Comment: Have in mind that every change that occurs on exported items since the export would be overwritten if the translated items are imported